# Custom JAX-RS serializer and deserializer for @QueryParam per endpoint

Tags: java, jax-rs, deserialization, unmarshalling

I have some REST endpoints that have to receive a parameter of `SecretData` class, for example:

```java
@GET
@Path(/*...*/)
public someInternalService(@QueryParam("data") SecretData outLittleSecret) {/*...*/}

@GET
@Path(/*...*/)
public someExternalService(@QueryParam("opaque") SecretData outLittleSecret) {/*...*/}
```

Now, given that `SecretData` conveys some non-public information, I'd like to have it encrypted when it comes from an external source (through that specific endpoint `someExternalService`).

The cryptographic procedure is not the point here. **The point is I have 2 representations for the same class of data.**

I can't have static `valueOf()` or `fromString()` implemented in class `SecretData`, because that would affect the other endpoint too.

**How can I provide a custom marshaller for the `SecretData` class that applies only for the `someExternalService` endpoint?**

Comment: Small Question: in your API, how do you plan to differentiate an Encripted `SecretData` instance from a non encripted `SecretData` instance ??

Comment: @CarlitosWay in the API the `SecretData` will appear as `String`. Other endpoints will return that string, and it should be treated as opaque data. The client has to provide it when necessary.

Comment: Is SecretData a POJO?? Or it just a string that in somecases is opaque and others not??

Comment: Definitely a POJO. To be externalized as some opaque string *sometimes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I provide a custom marshaller for the SecretData class that applies only for the someExternalService endpoint?

Well, AFAIK, you can't (see note #3). But you can resolve your problem using *separation of concerns* and creating a hierarchical design of your API... let me explain ...

Assume that `Data` is your master object (it will be what you call now as "plain" `SecretData`), it contains the info that internal (or external) services want to transmit ...

```
public class Data {
    protected int attribA;
    ...
    protected String attribN;

    public static Data valueOf(String data) {
        // here, you transform the string and set
        // the corresponding attributes values
    }
}
```

Then, you can define an endpoint like this:

```
@GET
@Path(/*...*/)
public someInternalService(@QueryParam("data") Data data) {/*...*/}
```

Now, for the external services, you create a new POJO ("separation of concerns") like this:

```
public class EncryptedData extends Data {
    // any attribute is inherited from data
    // this class does not expose new attributes

    /**
     * Copy constructor.
     */
    EncryptedData(Data data) {
        super();
        this.attribA = data.attribA;
        ...
    };

    public static EncryptedData valueOf(String opaque) {
        // here, you transform the encrypted String into
        // a regular String, then you call Data.valueOf ...
        // example:
        String decrypted = decrypt(opaque);
        return new EncryptedData( Data.valueOf(decrypted) );
    }
}
```

Then, your external services endpoint will look like:

```
@GET
@Path(/*...*/)
public someExternalService(@QueryParam("opaque") EncryptedData data) {/*...*/}
```

**NOTE:** Because `EncryptedData` IS_A `Data` instance, you can pass such object to any other method that receives a `Data` instance as input! So, you don't need to make any other transformations ...

**NOTE2:** apparently, if you are using RestEasy as JAXRS implementation, you can define a customizable String serializer ... see [StringConverter](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.6.2.Final/userguide/html/StringConverter.html#d4e1570)

**NOTE3:** checking the restEasy docs, **JAX-RS 2.0** does contain a way to create your custom serializer ... see [ParamConverter](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.6.2.Final/userguide/html/StringConverter.html#d4e1552) ... Under this strategy, you will need to create two ParamConverters (one for plain `SecretData` and one for opaque `SecretData`); and the ParameterConverter Factory (the implementation of interface `ParamConverterProvider`) ... if you check the interface docs, the interface exposes only one method and such method receives the annotations applied to the parameter to be (de)serialized ... so, you will receive (I think) something like: `@QueryParam("data")` or `@QueryParam("opaque")` and based on those values you can create the ParameterConverter accordingly!